# How to find the number of real roots of the given equation?

Tags: roots

> The number of real roots of the equation $$2 \cos \left( \frac{x^2+x}{6} \right)=2^x+2^{-x}$$ is
>   (A) $0$, (B) $1$, (C) $2$, (D) infinitely many.

Trial:  $$\begin{align} 2 \cos \left( \frac{x^2+x}{6} \right)&=2^x+2^{-x} \\ \implies \frac{x^2+x}{6}&=\cos ^{-1} \left( \frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2} \right)\end{align}$$ Then I can't proceed.

Comment: Well, your form, or the original, are enough to rule out infinity. And can you see an obvious solution?

Comment: Can you show that the left side is at most $2$, while the right side is at least $2$?

Comment: Is it safe to assume a knowledge of calculus?  Can you tell where the right hand side has a minimum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a clever approach to this problem. In particular, $$(w-1)^2 \geq 0 \implies w^2 + 1 \geq 2w \implies w + \frac{1}{w} \geq 2$$

and this works for any $w$. Using this, you can show that one side is always at least $2$. Meanwhile, the other is at most $2$.

Comment: "and this works for any $w$" -- you mean any *positive* $w$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\text{So, }(2^x)^2- 2^x\cdot2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)+1=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in $2^x$

As $x$ is real, so would be $2^x$ 
so,the discriminant must be $\ge 0$

i.e., $$\{2 \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)\} ^2-4\cdot1\cdot1\ge0$$

$$\implies4\left(\cos^2\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)-1\right)\ge0$$

$$\implies  \sin^2\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)\le 0$$

$$\implies  \sin^2\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)= 0\text{ as the square of a real number }\ge 0 $$

So, the discriminant must be $0,\implies \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)=\pm1$

$\implies 2^x=\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)\pm\sqrt{2 \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)\}^2-4\cdot1\cdot1}}2=\pm1$

As $x$ is real, $2^x>0$
$\implies 2^x=1\implies x=0$ which also satisfies $ \sin^2\left(\frac{x^2+x}6\right)= 0$

Answer (score 2):

If you consider $f(x)=2^x+2^{-x}$ and notice how it is symmetrical around $x=0$ and has its minimum there as for example $f(1)=2.5$ and $f(2)=4.25$, which the left hand side has a maximum value of 2, thus there is only one possible root though I'll leave that for you to see.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $2^0+2^0=2$ and that $2^x+2^{-x}> 2$ for $x\ne 0$.  Then consider that $2\cos(0)=2$ and that $2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)\le2$ for all $x$.  What can we conclude?

Answer (score 1):

1. $RHS=2^x+2^{-x}=2^x+\frac{1}{2^x}\geq 2$ by $AM\geq GM$, since $2^x>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $LHS\leq 2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This is obvious.
3. One can verify $x=0$  is a solution.
4. $f(x)=2^x+2^{-x}$ implies $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

These should suffice to conclude the unique solution at $x=0$.