# Number of real roots of an equation

Tags: trigonometry

What is the number of real roots of the equation

$$2\cos(\frac{x^2 + x}{6}) = 2^x + 2^{-x}$$

How to solve this kind of problems. Any general methods ??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380896/how-to-find-the-number-of-real-roots-of-the-given-equation

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Minimum value of RHS =2.

Answer (score 1):

By $AM-GM$,
$$\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2} \geq \sqrt{2^x2^{-x}} = 1$$
$$\implies 2^x+2^{-x} \geq 2$$

with equality only when $2^x = 2^{-x}$, i.e. $x=0$.

Also, $$2\cos(\frac{x^2+x}{6}) \leq 2$$

So the only solution is when $LHS=RHS=2$. The only olution for $RHS=2$ is $x=0$, which also turns out to be a solution for $LHS$.

Hence there is exactly one real root, $x=0$.